# JetPack Compose onClick function

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Please try to tolerate my inexperience.

I'm practicing Jetpack Compose navigation. I making an app that displays a set of card in a LazyHorizontalGrid format, and when clicked it navigates to a screen (destination) containing details of the card, depending on which card is clicked.

Here's what I mean:

[image]

I want to navigate to a screen (destination) that describe a particular "Favorite Collections" when clicked, depending on which is clicked.

I was following a tutorial on youtube, but I got lost when he was using `Companion Object` on a new activity (i.e having multiple activity in a single project and navigating by intent), since that's not recommended I'm not doing that, **so I don't know** where to put my `Companion Object`.
[RecyclerView in Jetpack Compose - Jetpack Compose For Beginners #7](https://youtu.be/OUu8_NEmAac?t=1707)

As I get errors when I try to put the `Companion Object` in the file of the Screen I'm trying to navigate to, *error*; `Modifier 'companion' is not applicable inside 'file'`, or In a Composable in the file, *then I get this error*; `Unresolved reference: companion`.

This is the screen I'm trying to navigate to (let's call it; DetailScreen);

```
@Composable
fun DisplayHomeInfo(){
    WelcomeText()
    HomeInfoDetails(homeInfo = )
}

@Composable
fun WelcomeText() {
    Text(
        text = "Welcome, to Home Information",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 18.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun HomeInfoDetails(homeInfo: HomeInfo) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape),
        elevation = 10.dp,
    ) {
        
   ....
```

This is the screen I'm trying to navigate from;

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(onHomeCardClick: () -> Unit) {
    HomeContentScreen(onHomeCardClick = onHomeCardClick)
}

....
```

Data class I want to load on the detail screen;

```
data class HomeInfo(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val sex: String,
    val age: Int,
    val description: String,
    val homeInfoImageId: Int = 0
)
```

And this is the Object I want to match with the data;

```
object HomeInfoModel {
        
    val homeInfoModelList = listOf(
        
        HomeInfo(
            id = 1,
            title = "Monty",
            sex = "Male",
            age = 14,
            description = "Monty enjoys chicken treats and cuddling while watching Seinfeld.",
            homeInfoImageId = R.drawable.ab1_inversions
        ),

        ...

    )
}
```

To summarize everything, **MY QUESTION** is how do I pass the data to the detailScreen, and show each card details, depending on the card clicked.

Please I understand my explanation is not very clear, and I'll be more than happy to clarify anything.

No information is too small, I will appreciate any help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into using [navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#navigation), maybe alongside a [view model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel),